# Understanding "ain't no fun when the rabbit got the gun"

Tags: slang

> "ain't no fun when the rabbit got the gun"

I came across the above slang recently. The explanation I could find on line is

> Someone being butthurt over having something, they do to others regularly, done to the them

For the literal meaning, my understanding is "It is not a fun (not an enjoyable thing) when the rabbit got the gun".

1. Is my understanding correct for the literal meaning?

Then I want to connect the literal meaning with its real meaning.

2. Why could "ain't no fun when the rabbit got the gun" have the meaning as shown by the online explanation?

Is it because, from the perspective of a hunter, you used to carry a gun and chased the rabbit, and then suddenly the situation turned -- the rabbit got the gun and pointed it at you?

Furthermore, I would like to know the implication when this slang is used.

3. What could the speaker imply when he or she says "ain't no fun when the rabbit got the gun"? Does the speaker imply that you should learn to accept the situation when "the rabbit got the gun"?

Some examples would be very appreciated.

Comment: Please note that you have misused the word "slang" throughout. *Slang* is strongly uncountable: it is used in the same way as the names of languages, e.g. English, French, Swahili, etc.

Answer (score 6):

This is just an expression of consternation due to the tables being turned on someone.  What has previously been an easy victory over someone or something has now become difficult or even impossible because the metaphorical "hunter" has become the metaphorical "prey".

Compare it with this other slang expression:

> Payback's a bitch.

Answer (score 4):

Think of Bugs Bunny and Elmer Fudd.

Elmer always Hunted Bugs Bunny. And always loved it.

But when Bugs got the Gun.

It wasnt so fun for Elmer

Comment: I think you've hit on the origin of the expression here. In the real world no rabbit is ever going to be able to use a gun even if it could get hold of one but Bugs, being an anthropomorphised cartoon character, most certainly could. Popular cartoon characters like Bugs and Elmer insinuate themselves into the general culture to such an extent that they need little, if any, explanation when they are referred to like this.

Comment: Also.  The movie Training Day

Answer (score 1):

Normally a hunter has the gun and is seeking the rabbit to shoot for a meal. It is not the preferred situation to find the rabbit with your gun. When the prey can shoot you with your own gun it is certainly no fun.

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, it’s pretty simple: a hunter hunts rabbits with a gun, typically. The rabbit is used as a metaphor for a person who is perceived as weaker, able to be taken advantage of, exploited, or just used in general. The hunter, in the metaphor, represents society or members of society who like to take advantage of people who they perceive to be weaker than them. In the case that the constantly exploited, perceived to be “weaker” person gets the gun, it becomes “no fun” because now the bullies of society, per se, are at risk of being shot for once. I hope that’s concise enough! :)

Answer (score 0):

The underlying implication is to see unfairness or privilege even when you are in the position of power. Do unto others as you would have them do to you. Because the tables can always turn.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

With my experiences I seen it like this, in certain environments you are in, very little could be valuable, and you’re always valuable. Eventually you may become hunted for your pelt. But you never knew you were ever gonna be set up, stuck up, robbed etc over trust. But when they see me over there with the sub-compact tucked off, it ain’t no fun when the rabbits got the gun.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).